# how to extract PHPSESSID from cURL header output

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl

I have a question:

If I set cURL to include header information in the output, how do I extract just the PHPSESSID information from that output?

The output looks something like that:

```
OUTPUT: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 26 Sep 2011 19:10:48 GMT    Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5 Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=lsa18d8r126ps1vfp4h05dh8r4; path=/ Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache     Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: how did you print this line? did you use echo? Please give a code example.

Comment: I got it by using curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true) then just echoed the output from curl_exec

Comment: ok, then I suspect you have to do it by hand with a regexp? Do you need code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple solution, I don't know if there is any curl way to retrieve that, but it can be handled with a simple regexp.

```
$foo="HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 26 Sep 2011 19:10:48 GMT    Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5 Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=lsa18d8r126ps1vfp4h05dh8r4; path=/ Expires: Thu,19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache     Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html";

echo preg_replace("/.*PHPSESSID=([^;]*);.*/", "\\1", $foo);
```

If the string is syntactically the same for every request you can do it as shown.
The ";" which marks the end of the session id is mandatory, else the regexp fails and returns the whole string, because it did not match. Maybe you should use a `preg_match` in front of a extraction to make sure it is syntactically correct or even there exists a `PHPSESSID` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some more code to parse out the headers out of the response. Unfortunately curl doesn't do that for you.

The following is a quick example on how to do that:

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';

// prepare curl
    $curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

// make request
    ob_start();
        $result = curl_exec ( $curl_handle ); // execute the curl command
    $response = ob_get_clean();

// parse the response
    $info = curl_getinfo( $curl_handle );
    curl_close( $curl_handle );
    $raw_headers = explode("\n", substr($response, 0, $info['header_size']) );

// Parse (named) headers
    $headers = array();

    foreach( $raw_headers as $header ){

        if( preg_match('/^(.*?)\\:\\s+(.*?)$/m', $header, $header_parts) ){
            $headers[$header_parts[1]] = $header_parts[2];
        }
    }

// get the body
    $body = substr($response, -$info['download_content_length']);  


// now you can get your headers from $headers by index
    echo $headers['PHPSESSID'];
```

A var_dump of the $headers array would look like this:

```
array(7) {
  ["Cache-Control"]=>
  string(19) "public, max-age=57
"
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(25) "text/html; charset=utf-8
"
  ["Expires"]=>
  string(30) "Wed, 14 Dec 2011 23:37:21 GMT
"
  ["Last-Modified"]=>
  string(30) "Wed, 14 Dec 2011 23:36:21 GMT
"
  ["Vary"]=>
  string(2) "*
"
  ["Date"]=>
  string(30) "Wed, 14 Dec 2011 23:36:23 GMT
"
  ["Content-Length"]=>
  string(7) "197298
"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only want to provide an improvement of @evildead's answer. His answer doesn't work in case the header output string contains line-breaks, or when cookie header ends just after sessid (so there's no semicolon).

```
$foo="HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 26 Sep 2011 19:10:48 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5 Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=lsa18d8r126ps1vfp4h05dh8r4; path=/ Expires: Thu,19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache     Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html";
preg_match("/PHPSESSID=(.*?)(?:;|\r\n)/", $foo, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

If could be a good idea to check PHPSESSID's existence too:

```
$foo="HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 26 Sep 2011 19:10:48 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5 Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=lsa18d8r126ps1vfp4h05dh8r4; path=/ Expires: Thu,19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache     Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html";
if(preg_match("/PHPSESSID=(.*?)(?:;|\r\n)/", $foo, $matches)){
    echo $matches[1];
}else{
    /* Do something */
}
```